# Ane Doki ending and the possibility of a sequel

Tags: manga-production, anedoki

So I was reminiscing about Mizuki-sensei's works and remembered Ane Doki's ending. For those of you who have read the manga, the ending was a big cliffhanger.

So I was wondering if there is a plan to have a sequel? Did Mizuki-sensei hint on it having a sequel? The manga could use a sequel you know, with an ending like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will not be a sequel. Ane Doki was a cancelled series due to being bottom five for weeks in WSJ (Weekly Shounen Jump). When a series gets cancelled due to low ratings, there will never be a sequel unless another magazine picks it up right away (which hardly ever happens).